# About RedirectToAction() in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session, layout, redirecttoaction

In a controller of `CourseUser`, I have this code:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
     if (Session["UserID"] == null)
     {
         return RedirecToAction("Login", "Home");
     }

     return View(db.ct.ToList());
}
```

I wanted to have the result to be show in `Home/Login`, but when the link is clicked, it always render the `CoureseUser/Index` first, result in the corresponding layout to be show

In the Layout for `CourseUser/Index`:

```
<a href="#">
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
     @Session["UserName"].ToString()
</a>
```

The section prevent the page to load properly after the session is cleared / abandon / timeout.

Is there any way for the `RedirectToAction()` to properly redirect to the `Home/Login`?

Answer (score 0):

Change the code in `CourseUser/Index` controller from

`return RedirecToAction("Login", "Home");`

into

`return RedirecToAction("Login", "Home", null);`